# drupal commerce discount product for base price

Tags: commerce, rules

I made several rules for discount. 10% off, 9% off, 8% off etc. The only problem is that the discount is calculated from the price included VAT. I want the discount calculated from the Subtotal price, without the VAT. But in rules i can't select that.
I followed this tutorial: https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/price-components

Strange thing is that when i only have 1 rule with discount it does work.

I am trying for hours, please help

Comment: The solution is here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49720/drupal-commerce-how-to-perform-a-complex-calculation-of-orders-final-cost-vat?rq=1